# How to select drop downs inside any div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs3

I am using ExtJs with Jquery. I have a panel under which I have check boxes, radios and drop downs. I am using the following code to get all the items under the panel.

```
    $('#panelId : input').each
```

This works for radio and check boxes. But, I am trying the following for drop down and it is not working

```
    $('#panelId : select').each
```

Experts please guide me.

Note: I am painting raw html into the panel using XTemplate. So I am not able to retrieve the items using extjs (Rather I don't know!). Can any one suggest the same using extjs?

Comment: `I am using ExtJs with Jquery` I dont understand, why someone work with two different framework like that.

Comment: can you please put the sample code.

Comment: @Derek I mean to say drop downs

Comment: @toopay Jquery just to get for functionality like this and ext js for all the components. I am not sure whether this is a good approach, but, its how our architecture was designed and we are going with it. To be frank, jquery simplifies things at many instances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:select is not a valid selector. Please read the [jQuery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

You can see a [quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLhQt/5/) here to see it working and help you understand how to use the proper input or select jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery selector function `$` expects a valid CSS selector as an argument.  If you want all `<select>` elements under the parent ID, then this should do what you want:

```
$('#panelId select').each(...
```

Note in the above that there's no colon between `#panelId` and `select`.  Colon characters in CSS are reserved for pseudo selectors like `:hover`.

If you want more than one kind of child element, you can specify multiple selectors by separating them with commas. e.g.

```
$('#panelId select, #panelId input').each(...
```

An even better way would be to start with the panel, then select just the matching descendants:

```
$('#panelId').find('select, input').each(...
```

Hope this helps!